# Can't create bootable usb key with windows 10

Tags: live-usb

Startup disk creator won't open the file. I click on "other", find the file, click on "open" (or double click the file), nothing happens.

Rufus - well, the "balena-etcher" equivalent - can't be securely installed.

```
sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/balena-etcher.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.2JnR7EAw3P/gpg.1.sh --keyserver hkps://keyserver.ubuntu.com:443 --recv-keys 379CE192D401AB61
gpg: keyserver receive failed: No such file or directory

sudo apt update

Reading package lists... Done     
W: GPG error: https://dl.bintray.com/etcher/debian stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 379CE192D401AB61
E: The repository 'https://deb.etcher.io stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

And unetbootin can't be found.

This is not the only issue. Microsoft has stopped putting sha256sum online, so I don't know whether my iso is OK.

Comment: I use Anyburn under windows do not like Rufus.

Comment: If you are making a Live or Persistent 20.04.2 install of Ubuntu to USB use the latest versions of the installers. In the past week I have used Rufus, Etcher, Universal YUMI, Ventoy and UNetbootin in Windows 10 and mkusb, Etcher, Disks and Ventoy in Ubuntu. Perhaps your ISO is bad. There are lots of sites to check MD5SUM, etc online: I have used: http://onlinemd5.com/ and https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/md5_checksum.html

Comment: If you need something securely installed, boot the ISO, either from scratch or using Ventoy. although Rufus, mkusb, Disks, Win32DiskImager and dd just make a clone of the ISO in ISO9660 format which is hard to beat for security.

Comment: Unetbootin site is working: https://unetbootin.github.io/